# hibernate nested query HQL/criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hql, criteria

I'm trying to express a somewhat complex query in hibernate either with HQL or Criteria but I didn't find the way. I'm aware that cannot expect the `orm` to solve everything but I'm not such an expert in hibernate and I got so closed that I'm hoping that I'm missing something silly.

I've been looking in SO for questions and there is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729097/nested-query-with-hql-hibernate) and nobody answered except the author, who gave up and posted a solution using plain `SQL`. So maybe I'm wasting my time and I should do the same. And maybe you consider this is a duplicate... I'm not sure.

The query I'm trying to build is

```
select * from user_rank
where user_id in (select user_id
    from (select user_id as user_id, row_number() over() as rownumber 
        from user_rank
        where ... additional parameters ...
        order by rank desc) as maxrows
    where rownumber <= :number)
and ... additional parameters ...
```

The table stores user ranking and I'm getting the top 5. The `row_number() over()` is just a trick for `postgresql` to be able to filter the top 5 in the outer query.

My closest attempt was for Criteria and it looks like this,

```
ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("id.userId"))
        .add(Projections.sqlProjection("row_number() over() as rownum", new String[] {"rownum"}, new Type[] { new IntegerType() }));

DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserRank.class)
        .addOrder(Property.forName("rank").desc())
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
        .setProjection(pl)

Criteria criteria2 = session.createCriteria(UserRank.class)
        .add(Property.forName("id.userId").in(subCriteria))
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
```

which would work except for the fact that it does not select the top 5 users. I cannot add the following to `subCriteria`

```
        .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("rownum <= 5"));
```

because the column `rownum` does not exist yet. And there is no way to add it in the `in` statement of `criteria2`. I guess I could paginate over the results and it would not be too slow?

I could also solve it like this surely it would be slower.

```
Criteria usersC = session.createCriteria(UserRank.class)
        .addOrder(Property.forName("rank").desc())
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
        .setProjection(pl);

// Java code that fetches from the query and creates the list `users`

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserPageRankEvolution.class)
        .add(Restrictions.in("id.userId", users))
        .add(Property.forName("... additional ..."))
```

With `HDL` I didn't get even closed.

Many thanks for your patience and for your help.

Comment: Found a solution? I'm having the same problem... I need paging in my subquery

Comment: No, I did not find any other solution than writing it in SQL. I guess HL has its limitations and mine was a weird case (although I guess everybody gets into a similar case from time to time). Cheers